# How can I use multiple cores for compiling a single crate?

Tags: rust

I have a single crate, which has around 10k lines of just struct and enums.

It takes between 10 and 60 seconds to run on my MacBook Pro 2.8Ghz dual core.

I used another Linux VM with 16 cores at 3.5Ghz, but compile time is roughly the same - it seems to only be using a single core.

Are there certain flags or workspace configurations I should be using?

Splitting the code into many crates can be done, but the dependency cycles between the types would mean I would need to just include all other workspace-crates types as `use workspace::crate-x::*` - would this still improve compile times?

What is it about workspaces that enables caching, but within a single crate no caching occurs?

I'd prefer not to split my code into arbitrary chunks just to enable cargo build caching.

Also, according to https://pingcap.com/blog/rust-huge-compilation-units, you can only have cyclic types inside a single crate as crate-crate imports must form a DAG.  So this would mean I cannot split my single crate into many without breaking the cyclic deps?

[image]

Comment: *Workspaces* don't do anything particularly special here. Multiple crates is the key, and workspaces just happen to be an optimization on multiple crates.

Comment: Related: [Parallel Compilation in the *Guide to Rustc Development*](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/parallel-rustc.html)